# Wordpress requires FTP information to update plug-ins

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to update Wordpress plug-ins, and I'm presented with the familiar FTP login screen.

I have read other posts indicating the lines in wp-config.php to be filled in. However, I don't have FTP installed on this server, just SFTP.

Also, I don't want to have to do this for each Wordpress install.

As far as I know, wp-content is already owned by apache:apache, and PHP is also running as user apache.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there some other way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying everything I could find regarding permissions, I added the following line of code to this site's wp-config.php:

define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');

That immediately solved the problem. Not sure if I also needed to modify the permissions first, since i did that before trying this fix.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me alot, when installing wordpress on my own server. Usually it has to do with a permission problem.

A lot webservers use the user www-data, instead of apache. So check your apache configuration for what your webserver user is set to.

Also you will want to check your directory permissions, and make sure both the user and group has read, write, and execute access. I am not sure if execute access is necessary, but that is usually what I set my server too.

You can do this with the command

chmod 775 -r your_wp_content_directory

And if all else fails, if you have shell access you can also use wget in the directory to install plugins.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I will post an update with the current perms.

Comment: drwxrwsr-x  6 apache    apache  4096 Sep  8 12:19 wp-content

Comment: Glad you got it work with define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');. Not sure why you would need to force wordpress write to the filesystem although. Thanks for showing me a new solution, to this common problem